# How can I get only specified fields back from Eventbrite API

Tags: python, python-3.x, eventbrite

I am currently working on a Python script that will eventually pull any of my live events from Eventbrite and export the attendees first and last name, date of birth and e-mail address.

However, being new to both Python and the Eventbrite API I am struggling with how to only get the fields I need directly from the API.

So far I have managed to get a list of all the events I am looking for using one of the code examples provided by Eventbrite, and have managed to also get a participant list from an event using an event id that I sourced from [Eventbrite API](https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/).

I have included the code that I have pulled together so far:

```
from eventbrite import Eventbrite

# My token i currently hard coded in
eventbrite = Eventbrite('MYTOKEN')

my_id = eventbrite.get_user()['id']

event_response = eventbrite.event_search(**{'user.id': my_id})

# The Event ID is hard coded in at the moment but want to iterate
# once I have a list of event ID's
attendees_response = eventbrite.get_event_attendees("EVENTID")

print("Event")
print(event_response)

# For debugging purposes
print("Attendees")
print(attendees_response)
```

The part that I am struggling to work out is how to specify I only want the event ID returned (that way I can store them in a list) when I do an event search and how to specify I only want the attendees first name, last name, DOB, and e-mail address when I build my attendees list.

Comment: Since the EventBrite API doesn't seem to take any flags that would indicate to the server that you only want specfic fields you'll have to take the `event_response` and map over it to extract all event ids.